# Zend Framework - 1.12 - Exceptions not being caught by the error controller

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework-mvc, zend-framework-modules

This question has been asked before and I have tried the solutions mentioned but nothing has worked for me.

In my controller whenever an exception is thrown rather then it being handled by the error controller I get an error message saying

> Error : Uncaught Exception xxx

To solve this I added the following in my application.ini

```
resources.frontController.throwExceptions = 0
```

but it didn't worked. I had added this inside the development section of the application.ini and I have checked the application is running in the development environment so this should get triggered.

I also tried adding following to my bootstrap class but it failed as well.

```
protected function _initErrorDisplaySettings() {
    $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance ();
    $front->throwExceptions ( false );
}
```

I can't figure out why the error controller is not being called. The error controller exists and the corresponding view script also exists.

I am using modules. Can this be the cause of this?

Can anyone please help me solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you throwing the exception and whats its stack trace?

Comment: @MikeB Right now I am throwing a custom exception with a dummy message from my controller, so stack trace won't help I guess. But if the exception is thrown from any where else like models or during the dispatch loop by the MVC components the same thing happens.